# Call first function on the class (Threads)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, function

My question is simple. How do I run the first function of this class(2) on another class(1)? 
(1) this class is my main class, (2) this one is the second, created inside the first one.

Code of class(2):

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    public ConnectedThread() {
        //This function!!!!!!!!!!!
    }

    public void run() {
        //blah blah blah
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        //blah blah blah
    }

    public void cancel() {
        //blah blah blah
    }
}
```

I got something in my code like `ConnectedThread connect;` and when I type `connect.` the program shows me "run()", "cancel()"... Everything but that function I want to run. How do I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: You use the 'new' keyword. Thats not a function really... its a specialized method called a constructor. EG ConnectedThread t = new ConnectedThread();

Comment: I dont want to turn it into a function. I want to run that piece of code on my main class... Thanks for your answer

Comment: FYI, when you use that constructor, you're not "running it on another class."  You're just "calling" it.  Constructors and methods are _called_ by other constructors and methods.  The other constructors and methods may be _in_ (or _belong to_) the same class or in other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ConnectedThread() is not a function there.It is the constructer of the class.If you want to make it function,than change it to public void ConnectedThread().But return type (eg:void) is not permited to use for constructor.So you should change the function name too.

```
public void functionName(){


}
```

Comment: I dont want to turn it into a function. I want to run that piece of code on my main class... Thanks for your answer